# How do I linear ramp to a position with the Web Audio API's pannernode?

Tags: web-audio-api

I can use the `linearRampToValueAtTime()` method of the Web Audio API's AudioParam Interface to schedule a gradual linear change in the param. For instance, for gain,

```
var gainNode = audioContext.createGain();
gainNode.gain.linearRampToValueAtTime(1.0, audioContext.currentTime + 2);
```

I want to linearly ramp the position of a PannerNode. A Panner has a setPosition method, but I don't see an associated AudioParam:

```
var pannerNode = audioContext.createPanner();
pannerNode.setPosition(xPosition, yPosition, zPosition);
```

Can I linearly ramp the position of a panner node? I know that I could manually create a timer, and directly call `setPosition` over time, but can the Web Audio API handle that for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.  It's one of the many things wrong with the initial AudioPanner design, and why it's being refactored into two different nodes. https://github.com/WebAudio/web-audio-api/issues/372.

For the time being, you'll have to animate this via setInterval or the like.

Comment: You can try the StereoPannerNode today in Firefox Nightly (and maybe Developer edition, not sure if it made the release), and maybe let us know what you think of it ?

Comment: Brilliant!  And actually StereoPanner is in Chrome Canary now too.